# Largest and smallest number that has k less digits in next number base

Tags: optimization, logarithms, closed-form, ceiling-and-floor-functions, number-systems

Let $n,k\in\mathbb N$, and $n\ge 2,k\ge 0$.

> Let $a_k(n)$ be the largest number that has $k$ less digits in number
>   base $n+1$ than in base $n$.
>
> Let $b_k(n)$ be the smallest number that has $k$ less digits in number
>   base $n+1$ than in base $n$.
>
> **Question.** How can we find closed forms (calculate efficiently) for these two sequences?

That is, a number $m\in\mathbb N$ has $\lfloor\log_nm\rfloor+1$ digits in number base $n$. This lead me to the following two identities, for the above two sequences:

$$a_k(n)=\max\{m\in\mathbb N:\lfloor\log_nm\rfloor-\lfloor\log_{n+1}m\rfloor=k\}$$

$$b_k(n)=\min\{m\in\mathbb N:\lfloor\log_nm\rfloor-\lfloor\log_{n+1}m\rfloor=k\}$$

After computing some values for these, it looks like the following holds:

$$\log_n(a_k(n)+1)=\left\lfloor\frac{(k+1)\log(n+1)}{\log(n+1)-\log(n)}\right\rfloor$$

$$\log_n(b_k(n))=1+\left\lfloor\frac{(k-1)\log(n+1)}{\log(n+1)-\log(n)}\right\rfloor$$

Where for second identity, for $k=0$, we take $b_0(n)=1$ instead, specially.

**Question.** How can we prove these two identities?

---

*Remark.*

For $k=0$, the following OEIS sequence seems relevant: [A031435](https://oeis.org/A031435), where we take $a_0(1)=1$.

Can we prove $\log_n(1+a_0(n))$ is equivalent to the linked OEIS sequence?